# Inclusion relation between norm spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Let $1\leq p\leq \infty$. For norms $||~~||$ on $\Bbb{K^n}$ defined by
$||x||_p=(|x(1)|^p+...+|x(n)|^p)^{1/p}$ and $||x||_\infty=\max\{|x(1)|,...,|x(n)|\}$.
Show that $$\bigcup_{1\leq p<\infty}\{x\in\Bbb K^n:||x||_p<1\}=\{x\in\Bbb K^N:||x||_\infty<1\}.$$

Attempt: $A=\bigcup_{1\leq p<\infty}\{x\in\Bbb K^n:||x||_p<1\}=\bigcup_{1\leq p<\infty}A_p$ and $\{x\in\Bbb K^N:||x||_\infty<1\}=B.$
Let $v\in A$ then $v\in A_p$ for some $p$. Then $||v||_p<1$. Letting $p\to\infty$$, ||v||_\infty<1$. Thus $v\in B$. Hence $A\subset B$.

To prove the reverse inclusion. Let $u\in B$.  Then $||u||_\infty<1$.
How to proceed next?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: how does it follow from $p\rightarrow\infty$ that $\|v\|_\infty<1$?
the argument for $A\subset B$ is very simple if you argue by contradiction

Comment: @PinkPanther In the previous problem I showed that $\lim_{p\to\infty}||x||_p=||x||_\infty$.

Comment: then you should write here that you know that. did you also show that $\|v\|_p\geq\|v\|_{p'}$ for $p<p'$ if $\|v\|_p<1$?
for $B\subset A$, notice that $\|v\|_p\leq n^{1/p}\|v\|_\infty$, then $\|v\|_p<1$ for large enough $p$.

Comment: @PinkPanther Yeah I have done . Thanks!